# ReactJs - Update element in Array with checkBox

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects to render some checkBox. But when I call the onClick or onChange function, my e.target.value is "on", I need to know the value of which element was clicked to update my state of the array with the new value of the checkbox.

```
let arrayNiveis = [
        {
            id: 1,
            codigo: 16,
            filhos: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    codigo: 17,
                    filhos: null,
                    marcado: false,
                    menu: 1,
                    nivel: 1,
                    nome: "Listar",
                    opcao: 2,
                    pai: 1
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    codigo: 19,
                    filhos: null,
                    marcado: false,
                    menu: 1,
                    nivel: 2,
                    nome: "Disponível",
                    opcao: 2,
                    pai: 1
                }
            ],
            marcado: false,
            menu: 1,
            nivel: 0,
            nome: "MANUTENÇÃO DE SERIAIS",
            opcao: 2,
            pai: null
        }
    ];

const [arrayGrupoNiveis, setArrayGrupoNiveis] = useState(arrayNiveis);

const handleCheckBox = (e: any) => {
        console.log("entro no check")
        arrayGrupoNiveis.map((nivelItem: any) => (
            nivelItem.codigo == e.target &&
            nivelItem.filhos.map((filho: any) => (
                filho.codigo == e.target &&
                (filho.marcado = !filho.marcado)
            ))
        ))
    };

return (
<FormProvider>
  {
    arrayGrupoNiveis.map((nivelItem: any) => (
      nivelItem.menu == 1 ?
        {
          nivelItem.filhos.map((filho: any) => (
            <Box sx={{ marginLeft: 4 }}>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                 `your text` <Checkbox
                    checked={filho.marcado}
                    size="small"
                    onClick={handleCheckBox}
                  />}
                label={filho.nome}
              />
              </FormControlLabel>
            </Box>
           ))
        }
      :
      <Box>
      </Box>
    ))
  }
</FormProvider >
);
```

I tried to pass the code of the father and son but it updates all the values, I need to update only the element that is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update only the element that is clicked I would add a dataset attribute on your "Checkbox" component (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) or simply the id of the element.

Something like that:

```
                 <Checkbox
                checked={filho.marcado}
                size="small"
                onClick={handleCheckBox}
                id={filho.id}
              />}
```

Then you access it in your function:

```
const handleCheckBox = (e: any) => {
    // The id of the clicked element.
    const eleId = e.target.id
};
```

And use it to retrieve the corresponding object to update in your state.

(Although it is not recommanded to use a number for the html id attribute I think you get the idea!).